# eps figures with pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, pstricks, eps

In a recent discussion on this site I learned that using

```
\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
```

makes it possible to run `pdflatex` on files containing `eps` and `pstricks` files (and `psfrag` usage as well). Now a couple of questions:

1. If a file does not contain `pstricks`, just `eps` and `psfrag`, this method can still be used. But is there a method to do this that does not require loading `pstricks`? I know that `auto-pst-pdf` is one approach, another one is to load `epstopdf`, are there any other ways to achieve this without loading these files? Maybe by adding an option to `graphicx`?
2. In all these approaches, every time that `pdflatex` is run all `eps` and `pstricks` files are converted to `pdf` files, even if they have not changed. Is there an approach that prevents it and only converts to `pdf` if a file has been changed from last compilation?

Thanks

Comment: Are the two subquestions actually related? If not, it might make sense to separate them.

Comment: I have to add that epstopdf cannot handle psfrag. Both auto-pst-pdf and \usepackage[pdf]{pstricks} handle psfrag with no problem.

Answer (score 18):

TeX Live 2010 and 2011 automatically convert EPS files to PDF, but it looks like it keeps converting, even when the EPS file hasn't changed. Working from Herbert's suggestion, this should do the trick. It may also work with other distributions, but I've not tried.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\epstopdfsetup{update} % only regenerate pdf files when eps file is newer
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{sine} % loads sine-eps-converted-to.pdf
\end{document}
```

Comment: On my system it does not keep converting if the eps file is not changed...  Maybe difference in epstopdf.cfg?

Comment: Maybe. I thought I had a stock TeX Live 2011 install on Windows with no explicit modifications to epstopdf.cfg, but things might be different on another OS, or I could simply be wrong about the auto-update, or the nature of my epstopdf.cfg.

Comment: aha... on Windows there could be problems with timestamps...  Sorry, I do not have a Windows box to check

Answer (score 15):

1. In a modern system a `foo.eps` file in `\includegraphics{foo}`, if present, is automatically converted to `foo.pdf` during `pdflatex` run.
2. This conversion is done only once, so `foo.pdf` is left for the next runs.  If you change your `eps` file, it will be regenerated.

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{tmp1}
\end{document}
```

When I ran it, I had file `tmp1.eps`, but no `tmp1.png` or `tmp1.pdf` in my working directory.  The log said:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <tmp1.eps>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2011-12-12 13:41:25
(epstopdf)                    size: 15351 bytes
(epstopdf)             Output file: <tmp1-eps-converted-to.pdf>
(epstopdf)             Command: <repstopdf --outfile=tmp1-eps-converted-to.pdf 
tmp1.eps>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 4.
runsystem(repstopdf --outfile=tmp1-eps-converted-to.pdf tmp1.eps)...executed sa
fely (allowed).

Package epstopdf Info: Result file: <tmp1-eps-converted-to.pdf>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2011-12-16 14:36:28
(epstopdf)                    size: 7774 bytes.

<tmp1-eps-converted-to.pdf, id=1, 346.00266pt x 37.00826pt>
File: tmp1-eps-converted-to.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)

<use tmp1-eps-converted-to.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: tmp1-eps-converted-to.pdf used on input line 4.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 346.0018pt x 37.00815pt.
```

as you see, the file was converted.  Then I ran `pdflatex` again:

```
Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <tmp1.eps>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2011-12-12 13:41:25
(epstopdf)                    size: 15351 bytes
(epstopdf)             Output file: <tmp1-eps-converted-to.pdf>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2011-12-16 14:36:28
(epstopdf)                    size: 7774 bytes
(epstopdf)             Command: <repstopdf --outfile=tmp1-eps-converted-to.pdf 
tmp1.eps>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 4.
Package epstopdf Info: Output file is already uptodate.

<tmp1-eps-converted-to.pdf, id=1, 346.00266pt x 37.00826pt>
File: tmp1-eps-converted-to.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
```

As you see, no conversion was done.

Then I changed my `tmp1.eps` and run `pdflatex again.  And the log said:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <tmp1.eps>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2011-12-16 14:40:16
(epstopdf)                    size: 620519 bytes
(epstopdf)             Output file: <tmp1-eps-converted-to.pdf>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2011-12-16 14:36:28
(epstopdf)                    size: 7774 bytes
(epstopdf)             Command: <repstopdf --outfile=tmp1-eps-converted-to.pdf 
tmp1.eps>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 4.
runsystem(repstopdf --outfile=tmp1-eps-converted-to.pdf tmp1.eps)...executed sa
fely (allowed).

Package epstopdf Info: Result file: <tmp1-eps-converted-to.pdf>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2011-12-16 14:40:21
(epstopdf)                    size: 19423 bytes.

<tmp1-eps-converted-to.pdf, id=1, 241.90375pt x 188.705pt>
File: tmp1-eps-converted-to.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)

<use tmp1-eps-converted-to.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: tmp1-eps-converted-to.pdf used on input line 4.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 241.90315pt x 188.70453pt.
```

As you see, *now* the file was regenerated!

Comment: This approach does not work for me (Miktex 2.9, updated regularly). I get the error message:! LaTeX Error: File `tmp1' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.4 \includegraphics{tmp1}
                          
?

Comment: Well, you may consider trying TeXLive for Windows... As @Mike-renfro says, it works in Windows TL

Comment: Regarding MiKTeX and `epstopdf` see also this answer of mine: [Including pdf figures in Latex document using TexnicCenter](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51916/including-pdf-figures-in-latex-document-using-texniccenter/52026#52026).

Comment: Note that you need to have `texlive-font-utils` installed, otherwise including eps graphics will still fail (with uninformative error messages). See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/231225/118248).

Comment: @oulenz Surely.  I assumed a full TeXLive or equivalent installation

Answer (score 5):

Regarding your first question: package `epstopdf` is a good choice when using eps images.

Regarding the second question: there is only a possibility to create no or all images.

Comment: I am afraid you are incorrect wrt second question :(  I thought the same, and then run tests.  epstopdf is VERY smart :)

Comment: I was referring to `pst-pdf` with the second part.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you...

Comment: The problem with epstopdf is that it cannot handle psfrag fragments.

Comment: @Per [`auto-pst-pdf`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/auto-pst-pdf) can...

Answer (score 3):

I tried many of the options cited in many posts. It is not `epstopdf` package, neither `-shell-escape`.

For me, the solution was to install `texlive-font-utils`

Comment: Strangely it worked for, I can't explain it