# Converted EPS not found with TeX Live 2012 and Windows 8

Tags: texlive, epstopdf

I use TeX Live 2012 on Windows 8 and would like to use an EPS image. I usually use PNG, but in this case PNG is too pixelated.

I found that `epstopdf` is the preferred solution and that TeX Live (starting in 2010) converts on the fly. TeX Live thinks it converted the file, but can't find it because it doesn't exist (log file below). I tried using absolute file references and turning off all other graphics packages, but the symptoms don't change.

This is a little deeper than I've gotten in TeX and would appreciate any help.

```
(c:/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
(./payout_content.tex
Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <../figures/gz_figure_1.eps>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2013-03-08 09:16:48
(epstopdf)                    size: 80137 bytes
(epstopdf)             Output file: <../figures/gz_figure_1-eps-converted-to.pd
f>
(epstopdf)             Command: <repstopdf --outfile=../figures/gz_figure_1-eps
-converted-to.pdf ../figures/gz_figure_1.eps>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 6.
runsystem(repstopdf --outfile=../figures/gz_figure_1-eps-converted-to.pdf ../fi
gures/gz_figure_1.eps)...executed safely (allowed).

Package epstopdf Info: Result file: <../figures/gz_figure_1-eps-converted-to.pd
f>.


! Package pdftex.def Error: File `../figures/gz_figure_1-eps-converted-to.pdf' 
not found.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.6 ...   \includegraphics{../figures/gz_figure_1}

Using draft setting for this image.
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
```

Comment: Not sure but it would simplify the interaction of the various programs a lot if instead of `../figures/gz_figure_1` you just had `gz_figure_1` and put the file in the current directory. Alternatively there is no need to convert this while doing atex you can just run ps2pdf gz_figure_1.ps and that should make a pdf file which pdflatex will then see,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- Wow. That does it. The file must be in the same directory with `epstopdf`? I tried full paths, but I guess it _has_ to be same directory. Thanks!

Comment: It's probably possible to configure things so it doesn't have to be in the same directory but it's easier just to simplify things so it works rather than configure things in a complicated way:-)

Comment: @RichardHerron See note at the end of section 1.3 in documentation of `epstopdf` (it’s part of the `oberdiek` bundle).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would simplify the interaction of the various programs a lot if instead of `../figures/gz_figure_1` you just had `gz_figure_1` and put the file in the current directory.

Alternatively there is no need to convert this while doing latex you can just run

```
ps2pdf gz_figure_1.ps
```

and that should make a pdf file which pdflatex will then see.

Comment: Thanks! FWIW, I added the `dEPSCrop` option so that `ps2pdf` doesn't embed in the eps file in a full page pdf file. That is, I run `ps2pdf -dEPSCrop gz_figure_1.esp`.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds a bit like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76455/converted-xxx-eps-converted-to-pdf-not-found/).

Try to insert `\epstopdfsetup{outdir=./}` into your header to make sure `epstopdf` generates the pdf files in the proper directory.