# epstopdf outdir challenges

Tags: epstopdf

I'm currently working on setting up the appendices for a dissertation project, which are going to contain +100 figures from several individual parametric studies.

The majority of the figures have are included as EPS-files hence the challenge relates to conversion of the many eps-files having. Note, the files have the same names across the subsets of the parametric studies. Therefore when having specified the epstopdf-outdir in the preamble** and consequently converting the picture files with epstopdf the files overwrite in some instances and others they don't so the result is a mess.

Using `renewcommand` appears inapplicable when trying to specify a subdirectory in the document body to the initially specified conversion-folder.

Any suggestions will be very appreciated.

** Suggested work-around to deal with error of converted files not found ([Converted EPS not found with TeX Live 2012 and Windows 8](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101476/converted-eps-not-found-with-tex-live-2012-and-windows-8/101938#101938)).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\epstopdfsetup{outdir=./figures/epstopdf_converted/}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Main report}
\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext

\appendix
\chapter{Parametric study}
\clearpage

\renewcommand{\epstopdfsetup}{outdir=./figures/epstopdf_converted/par_stud-A/} 
\section{Subset A}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{figures/par_stud-A/example.eps}
\caption{Parametric study - subset A.}
\label{fig:A-example}
\end{figure}
\clearpage

\renewcommand{\epstopdfsetup}{outdir=./figures/epstopdf_converted/par_stud-B/}
\section{Subset B}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{figures/par_stud-B/example.eps}
\caption{Parametric study - subset B.}
\label{fig:B-example}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Folder structure and examples of eps files can be obtained here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fi3hwr93ylbpruo/epstopdf_outdir_example.zip

Answer (score 3):

The error is here:

```
\renewcommand{\epstopdfsetup}{outdir=./figures/epstopdf_converted/par_stud-A/}
```

This destroys `\epstopdfsetup` and the setting `outdir` is *not* seen by package `epstopdf`.

Use `\epstopdfsetup` directly:

```
\epstopdfsetup{outdir=./figures/epstopdf_converted/par_stud-A/}
```