# EPS figure shows error when compiling with pdflatex

Tags: graphics, eps

I have trouble with EPS figure when compiling with `pdflatex`. I have compiled the following TeX code with `pdflatex`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[height=3 cm,width=4 cm,angle=0]{fig1.jpg}
\caption{Flower}
\end{center}
\label{fig2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

It is OK, there is no problem. But when I am using EPS image extension and compiling `pdflatex`, shows an error : 'unknown file extension `.eps`'. Now my question is : How can I compile TeX file containing EPS image extension with `pdflatex`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This question is very similar to [Why can't pdflatex print EPS figures?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/383/10102) and [eps figures with pdflatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38524/eps-figures-with-pdflatex). Please take a look at it as the information there might help you.

Comment: If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: According to above link I have used "\usepackage{epstopdf} in the preemble
Include graphics without extension e.g \includegraphics{picture}" But this shows error : 'fig1-eps-converted-to-.pdf, not found.

Comment: In that case maybe have a look here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76455/converted-xxx-eps-converted-to-pdf-not-found