# How to include EPS figures using pdfLaTeX?

Tags: eps, ieeetran, epstopdf

I have read the numerous related questions on this site, but I still couldn't get it to work. I followed instructions from [this answer:](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/387/17444)

```
\documentclass[journal, a4paper]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!t]
\includegraphics{overnondomination}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The output is:

```
*****
*****     PDFLaTeX output: 
*****     cd "/home/martin/MyArticles/Minimum_example"
*****     pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode example.tex
*****
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
 \write18 enabled.
...
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `overnondomination-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found.
```

Please, could you help me find out what I am doing wrong?

EDIT:

As suggested, the problem happened before this error message. It turned out that I had not installed `epstopdf`.

Running

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-font-utils
```

solved the problem.

Comment: Cannot reproduce your problem. :(

Comment: @Ch'enMeng Maybe you have a newer version of TeX Live

Comment: Unfortunately I also cannot reproduce the problem, with the same version of pdfTeX: `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)`. Is it true that the file `overnondomination-eps-converted-to.pdf` doesn't exist? Can you post more of your output? (If the answer to the first question is 'yes', presumably there is an error message for the file conversion, and seeing it might help work out what is going on here.)

Comment: Also, possible solution at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76455/converted-xxx-eps-converted-to-pdf-not-found?rq=1.

Comment: @Ant thank you! You were right. I just didn't have epstopdf installed on my computer. I had no idea it was a standalone program :)

Comment: @MartinDrozdik Contained by TeX Live, `epstopdf` can be installed by TeX Live. However, I don't know which component you should select, when setting up TeX Live, because I installed all parts of TeX Live. :(

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem due to missing essential software (incomplete installation)

Comment: @egreg Should I delete the question? Maybe someone has the same problem as me and for the same reason as me.

Comment: You can add an answer, if you prefer. In that case I'll retract my closing vote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After examining the output closer I found out that the file `overnondomination-eps-converted-to.pdf` was never created.

This is because I had not installed `epstopdf`.

Running

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-font-utils
```

solved the problem.