# pdftex.def Error: File logo-eps-converted-to.pdf not found

Tags: graphics, pdftex, eps, epstopdf

I am using the [EPFL thesis template](http://phd.epfl.ch/thesistemplates) to write a LaTex document. I need to compile it using `pdfLaTex`. Also, I want to use these same template - I can't use any other template. I have many EPS figures which I am unable to include as it throws me the following error

> Package epstopdf Info: Source file:  (epstopdf)
>
> date: 2014-03-22 17:37:02 (epstopdf)                    size: 1694
>
> bytes (epstopdf)             Output file:
>
> (epstopdf)             Command:
>
> -to.pdf images/logo> (epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 14.
>
> runsystem(repstopdf--outfile=images/logo-eps-converted-to.pdf images/logo.eps)...executed safely (allowed).
>
> Package epstopdf Info: Result file:
>   .
>
> ! Package pdftex.def Error: File
>   `images/logo-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found.

I have included the `graphicx` and `epstopdf` packages but to no change.I have installed [MacTex](http://www.tug.org/twg/mactex/) packages and I am using [TexStudio](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net) as my LaTex editor.

Is there a way I can include EPS figures without running into these problems? Please note that if I don't use this template and write a normal LaTex document these problems do not arise. I have also tried with other thesis templates and I receive exactly the same problem. I would like to find a solution for such a thesis template itself.

Thanks!

**Edit1**

Someone has asked me for a piece of code. The [zip file for the EPFL thesis template](http://phd.epfl.ch/files/content/sites/phd/files/shared/0%20Pages%20EDOC/Modeles_these/latex_template5_56.zip) has a file named `titlepage.tex`. This file includes the EPFL logo (as PDF) within LaTex. I just need to include an `EPS` image. Here's the relevant code but it's a standard piece of code to include figures in LaTex. `logo` is the EPS image.

```
\begin{tabular} {cc}
\parbox{0.3\textwidth}{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{images/logo}}
&
```

I am able to include `PNG`, `PDF` and `JPG` images but I want to include `EPS` images for many reasons.

**Edit2**

This seems to be a TexStudio issue (also mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76455/converted-xxx-eps-converted-to-pdf-not-found#comment163694_76455)). It works absolutely good with [TexShop](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/). Strange!

Comment: Have you tried to convert the files from eps to pdf using something like ghostscript or Adobe Destiller? I know it's not really an easy solution if you have many eps-figures, but a solution none the less.

Comment: Can you add a simple example of code?

Comment: @Argo I can do that, but it defeats the purpose - doesn't it?

Comment: @egreg The EPFL zip file for the thesis template has a file named `titlepage.tex` and it includes LaTex code to include the EPFL pdf image. I want to include an eps image instead of PDF. In any case, I will add some code in the original question.

Comment: @Dexter I can't understand the `xxx-eps-converted` bit: it should have a different name than `xxx`.

Comment: @egreg `xxx` is a pseudonym. Replace `xxx` by your favourite file name. `FooBar`? :)

Comment: I see no EPS file in the ZIP archive

Comment: @egreg Yes, there is no EPS in the ZIP archive like I mentioned in my edit. They use a PDF image but I want to include a EPS image.

Comment: I put an EPS file inside `images` and added `\includegraphics{name}` in the sample document; after adding `\usepackage{epstopdf}` to the preamble everything went smooth. Do you have a space in the file name?

Comment: @egreg Where did you add `\usepackage{epstopdf}`? I added it to two files `settings_custom.tex` as well as `my_thesis.tex`. Both gives me the same converted-pdf not found error.

Comment: @Dexter What's the name of the EPS file? The package can be loaded in `settings_custom.tex`. But spaces in the file name are not allowed.

Comment: @egreg - the name of the file is `logo.eps` and I have used `\includegraphics{logo}` in my LaTex file.

Comment: @Dexter Did you put it in the `images` directory? If you did, you should use `\includegraphics{images/logo}`

Comment: @Dexter: (a) Please, clean up the file name mess in the question. (b) Check, if the `.eps` file can be converted at all (`epstopdf` or `ps2pdf`).

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek - Done both and the image can be converted to a PDF. I still get the `! Package pdftex.def Error: File `images/logo-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found.` error.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the source file which you run the tex. I had same error, than I realised that I copied my tex file from another file. so you need to look at path file of your pdf or eps extended figure maybe.

```
\graphicspath{{C:/blabla/blabla//figures/}}
```

hope this fix the problem