# Package pdftex.def Error: File `images/p1-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found

Tags: graphics, import, epstopdf

I am using a Mac Machine with the following LaTeX Softwares:

- MacTEX: as the main LaTeX kernel
- TexStudio: as the LaTeX editor
  http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/

In part of the document I have created, I try to import a vector graphic image in `*.eps` format:

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
       \begin{tabular}{cc}
        \includegraphics[width=0.450\linewidth]{images/p1}& 
        \includegraphics[width=0.450\linewidth]{images/p2}\\ 
        (a)OLS & (b)RR 
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

`p1` and `p2`are `p1.eps` and `p2.eps` images.I include the following packages as well on top of the code:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
```

After this, I am getting a stupid error with regard to eps to pdf conversion.

```
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `images/p1-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found.
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `images/p2-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found.
```

I have tried several options but still cannot see the images in my machine. What can I do to overcome the issue please?

Comment: What do you mean please? Could you elaborate abit more?

Comment: Read carefully the [linked question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76455/converted-xxx-eps-converted-to-pdf-not-found) (and its answers) and read your .log file to understand the problem.