# Including eps graphics and compiling with pdflatex gives a pdftex.def Error: File 'xxx-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found

Tags: graphics, eps, epstopdf

I am storing my graphics in a directory contained in the parent folder of my main.tex file:

```
/parent
     /main
          /main.tex
     /graphics
          /figure.eps
```

I add that directory to my graphics path in the setup:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}   % Including figure files
\usepackage[outdir=/home/username/Paper Production/graphics/]{epstopdf}
...
\graphicspath{{../graphics/}}

...
...

\begin{figure}
 \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{multi_relation.eps}
 \caption{blabla}
 \label{blabla}
\end{figure}
```

I read another thread here [Converted xxx-eps-converted-to.pdf not found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76455/converted-xxx-eps-converted-to-pdf-not-found) where the solution was to use the epstopdf package and specify the outdir. I tried to do that above. However I get this error when I try to import eps graphics:

```
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `/home/username/PaperProduction/graphics/multi_re
lation-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found.
```

Also same when I use `outdir=../graphics/`. Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong?

Comment: by default tex is prevented from writing to files not below the current directory (eg `../anything`) for security reasons.  Is there any reason for not having the files locally?

Comment: also you show PaperProduction with no space in the error message but  `Paper Production` with a space in your path. (I'd avoid spaces in directory names)

Comment: Ok I see, it works now thanks a lot. Also, I'm not sure what's up with the space thing, it just seems to have been cut in the error ouput, but it works otherwise so oh well :D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default tex is prevented from writing to files not below the current directory (eg ../anything) for security reasons.