# Is it possible to have pictures in .pdf and .eps in LaTeX?

Tags: graphics, pdf, eps

I am a beginner in LaTeX and I want know if there is a way to have 2 images of different types in LaTeX:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} % espanol
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % acentos sin codigo
\usepackage{graphicx} % gráficos
\usepackage{subfigure} % subgráficos

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
 \includegraphics[scale=1.8]{figura/pantalla1.eps}
    \caption{IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII. }
\label{fig:interfas}
\end{figure} 

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
 \includegraphics[scale=1.8]{figura/pantalla1.pdf}   %error also if .png error 
    \caption{IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII. }
\label{fig:interfas2}
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

I have in all my documents `.eps`, and all looks excellent but 
I need to put 2 images in `.pdf` or `.png`, and if I convert it 2 images and `.eps` looks so bad because they are screen shot of cell.

Comment: Yes, use [`epstopdf`](http://ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf) as part of your document preamble and enable `-shell-escape` so the images can be converted in the background. See [EPS figures with `pdflatex`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38524/5764) and/or use [`epspdfconversion`](http://ctan.org/pkg/epspdfconversion). You will have to compile with `pdflatex`, regardless.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The image types you can include depend on whether you use latex or pslatex, and if you use latex they depend on the dvi driver (usually dvips) that you use. So it is better to omit the extension

```
\includegraphics[scale=1.8]{figura/pantalla1}
```

Rather than

```
\includegraphics[scale=1.8]{figura/pantalla1.eps}
```

then if you use pdflatex it will find a pdf (or png) version and if you use latex it will find a eps (or png).

Of course for bitmaps it may be best if possible to generate them at the correct size rather than scale them on inclusion as they do not necessarily scale so well.

Do not use `[H]` on figures unless you are absolutely sure you want that, and if you are sure you want that, try to persuade yourself otherwise:-)

Answer (score 2):

As Werner stated, you could use the on-the-fly method for eps to pdf conversion... 
 As an alternative convert the `.pdf` file to `.eps` and then use the usual latex command.  Regarding the `.png` file: converting it to `.eps` or `.pdf` will almost always look awkward... pdflatex can include `.png` and `.jpg` files!

By the way: Screen shots look nicer when the document is printed, on-screen document scale badly however.

Comment: Interesting, I would have said that deficiencies in bitmaps are much more apparent when the document is printed, you generally need quite high `dpi` (>300) to make a passable printed result.

Comment: @ach: Perhaps my statement on quality of printed screen shots was too positive. I helped a former colleague writing a book in LaTeX years ago. That book was published actually and contained about 10 screen shots which looked quite nice in the final hardcopy output.