# Include both eps and png figures, problem with dvipdfmx

Tags: eps, png, dvipdfmx

I want to include both `.eps` and `.png` figures in a latex document. I did some research and find out the solution is to use dvipdfm package. However, this package does not include my `.eps` files in the document and report following warnings:

`$ dvipdfmx test.dvi`

`** WARNING ** "ps: plotfile" found (not properly implemented)`

I am using following headers in my `.tex` file:

```
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
\input{psfig.sty}
```

I used to stack Latex, dvi2ps, ps2pdf command to get a `.pdf` file including `.eps` figures.

I use following command to include figures in the documet:

```
\begin{figure}[bthp] 
    \centerline{\psfig{figure=Results/Rsrch.Evict.eps,width=5in}}
    \caption{Total workload }
    \label{fig:ftl-map}
\end{figure}
```

Any idea to fix this issue ?

Comment: See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/120323/27635) of a your [namesake](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/31105/arh) and [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38524/27635), too.

Comment: don't use psfig unless you are trying to emulate a LaTeX 2.09 document from 1985.

Answer (score 1):

With `pdflatex --shell-escape` with TeX Live 2013  (and probably `--enable-write18` in MikTeX) you can make directly a PDF including  both PNG and EPS files. A MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
%http://creativecommons.org/about/downloads
\includegraphics{by-nd.png}
\includegraphics{by-nd.eps}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

In place of the EPS file really is used a PDF copy generated on the fly by `epstopdf` (in spite that the package of the same name was not included in the preamble). Try `\usepackage{epstopdf}` if this MWE fail in your computer).

Comment: In MiKTeX `--enable-write18` is the original switch, but `--shell-escape` works as well. But I had to include `epstopdf` explicitely in MiKTeX: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52026/9237 (just tested again: still valid).