# Using a forloop to generate PDF output of eps stata files

Tags: pdftex

I'd like to create a PDF file which, for now, contains only the image output I've generated in stata.

The images are all located in a folder called \network\location and all follow a common naming convention, file1,file2,...,filen.

The latex engine i want to use is pdfLaTex within Teworks.

I've written the following code to generate the file via pdflatex, but the process bombs before completion.  The specific error message is "Missing $ inserted,  $

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \foreach\x in {1,2,...,10}{%
    \includegraphics[height=5.4cm]{//network/location/file\x}
  }
\end{figure}  
\end{document}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why `//network/...` and not just `network/...`?

Comment: You should run `latex` > `dvips` > `ps2pdf` as the compilation sequence, not `pdflatex`. The latter cannot include EPS images. Or you could convert the images from EPS to PDF first, then run with `pdflatex`, or convert on-the-fly using the `epstopdf` package (`\usepackage{epstopdf}`, [EPS figures with `pdflatex`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38524/5764)).

Comment: @Werner that's true but does not explain the error described. I get no error (other than missing file 10 times) if I run the supplied example document.

Comment: do you get the described error if you run the exact tex file posted? (I do not) if you do can you add the log file to your question.

Comment: ...please delete the `.aux` *before* generating a new `.log`.

Comment: I figured out the issue -- for now.  i had to include ".eps" at the end of the filename.  I assumed it would pic up any and all images.
My new issue is how to have each image show up on a new page.  Completely green to latex.  Thanks for any help.

I solved the eps issue by using the epstopdf package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your comment query, do you want something like this (plus the epstopdf package etc.):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
  \foreach\x in {1,2,...,10}{%
  \begin{figure}
      \includegraphics[height=5.4cm]{//network/location/file\x}
      \caption{file\x}
   \end{figure}\clearpage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!