# Using a for loop to loop through sequentially named tex files

Tags: pdf, loops

I'd like to loop through all .tex files in a directory using code that looks like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=1cm,vmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\foreach\x in {1,2,...,12}{%
     \input{//network/path sub1/path sub2/test_\x.tex}
         \newpage
\thepage
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

For some reason, I  cannot get the '\x; to properly resolve to a number.

Further, I'd like to specify where the output gets saved.  Is that possible?

I tried to port over the code found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153240/using-a-forloop-to-generate-pdf-output-of-eps-stata-files), but had no success.  Any help?

Comment: You forgot to close the loop, please put another `}` at the right of `test_\x.tex}`.

Comment: Thanks!  Too many hours in front of the screen.  Knew something was missing from the loop.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it simply stems from unmatched braces.