# xxx-eps-converted-to.pdf

Tags: graphics

I'm using TeXworks with MiKTeX to make a LaTeX document.

When I try to render the document as pdf at the place where my EPS figure is supposed to be displayed I get a white box with black borders with the text "filename-eps-converted-to.pdf"

I have no idea what's causing this.

I'm using [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx), and the code to display is :

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics{exfig}
  \caption{Default}\label{fig:default}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Somewhere you have the `draft` option. Presumably in the option list for the document class. If you drop it, the undesired behaviour will disappear.

Comment: I've checked, didn't spot it.

Comment: Then you will have to provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that *clearly* reproduces the unwanted effect.

Comment: `pdflatex`cannot handle eps-files directly. You may convert the eps to pdf beforehand. Recent TeX installations should do the convertion on the fly (and obviously yours tries do it), but I didn't test it. Look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38524/eps-figures-with-pdflatex