# EPS to PDF conversion done by pdflatex is blurry

Tags: pdftex, pdf, eps, epstopdf

I have done a figure using TikZ that uses the shadows.blur package. Using qtikz (my TikZ editor), I have exported the image as an eps file.

In my document, I use `\includegraphics{theimage}` and pdflatex automatically convert my eps to a pdf (theimage-eps-converted-to.pdf). However, when there is a shadow, the image is not vectorial! (if I manually do epstopdf, I have the same issue in the pdf)

If I export in pdf directly from qtikz, the image is exactly as expected. So my question is: is there a way to fix the way pdflatex converts my eps files?

Comment: _How_ is the eps converted? `pdftex` doesn't do that.

Comment: @MartinSchröder `pdflatex` does that automatically.

Comment: Normally it doesn't. And I was the maintainer once. Are you using MikTeX?

Comment: I don't know what is MikTex. I only use pdflatex on my Debian.

Comment: Then I'm very curious _what_ you do to get the eps converted. Please edit your question to include a complete minimal example.

Comment: @MartinSchröder You can read the answers of this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38524/eps-figures-with-pdflatex The first answer states: "TeX Live 2010 and 2011 automatically convert EPS files to PDF". `epstopdf` is apparently used for the conversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the shadowing uses PDF features, which are not available in PostScript.
From the documentations, [`pgf-blur`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgf-blur/pgf-blur.pdf):

> This effect can be achieved in TikZ/PGF with the circular drop shadow
>   key,

And from the [PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf):

> In addition to the general `shadow` option, there exist special options
>   like `circular shadow`. These can only (sensibly) be used with a special
>   kind of path (for `circular shadow`, a circle) and, thus, they are not
>   as general. The advantage is, however, that they are more visually
>   pleasing since these shadows blend smoothly with the background. Note
>   that these special shadows use fadings, which few printers will
>   support.

Export the image as PDF and pdfTeX can include it directly without the need to run a converter for the down-graded PostScript file (the conversion is actually done by ghostscript).

Comment: "Note that these special shadows use fadings, which few printers will support." => Is that something I should worry about? Or if I use pdf it does not matter?

Comment: I think, it is quite ok for the PDF format, it is the job of the PDF printing program to make it appropriate for the printer (converting to bitmaps, ...).

Comment: an "ff" ligature was missing from the first quote, in "e...ect".  fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem (so happy, and I share):

Step 1: Remove the entire MikTeX exists on your computer using the Control Panel, after removing deleted folder named MikTeX in C:\ Program files (x86 ) to avoid errors when resetting because the same name folder (uninstall is complete without restarting the computer)

Step 2: Reinstall the MikTeX below (no need to install the program editor as texstudio, Texmaker, viettex, ...), this error is due to foundation MikTeX

MikTeX file download link: click [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/bnv2g6paahb91vh/MikTex_2.8_NHC.rar/file)

After downloading, you unzip. Installation file named setup-2.8.3553.exe in directory MikTeX /setup

Step 3: Install the file setup-2.8.3553.exe as usual, remember to tick select Complete MikTeX to install the full version.

Note when using:

Note 1: The order declaring the package ordered to order from top to bottom as follows:

\ usepackage {graphicx}

\ usepackage {epstopdf}

\ usepackage {subfigure}

Note 2: Before running TeX files, please ensure that you have deleted the corrupted PDF files are output from run error before (just leave a tail .eps image file)

Please vote me if it works !!!!

Coppy right: https://nhcan.wordpress.com/2020/04/05/loi-khi-bien-dich-file-latex-co-hinh-anh-dinh-dang-eps/