# When including two continuous eps figure, the secondary figure is blurry

Tags: eps

the code:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp] 
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure/1.eps}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htbp] 
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure/2.eps}
\end{figure}
```

By the way, the eps figures are exported by tecplot.

the sample blurry figure likes:(only the text on the secondary figure)
[image: the blurry figure]

12/22/2016,

Thanks @Bernard, it realy is the problem of the fonts. when I change it to the Times New Roman, the text become clear. BUT if I only need the orgin fonts, what can I do to make sure the text is still clear?

Comment: What happens if you include that figure on its own? Also, what happens if you zoom in close in your viewer? Is the text still blurred?

Comment: Welcome! Look at the http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194993/eps-to-pdf-conversion-done-by-pdflatex-is-blurry.

Comment: If only the text is blurry, I guss it's a problem with the fonts used by Tecplot.

Comment: What are the natural widths of the eps graphs? Is one of them being enlarged considerably by making it as wide as `\textwidth`?