# eps format not showing in my TeXworks to pdf file

Tags: epstopdf

I posting this question but once I posted in this topic ''LaTeX - Image not showing up'' I have bben told that to create new question that everyone can see.
I have a problem with .eps format when I want to convert my text form TeXworks to pdf file. I always get the blank rectangle with name of the image! I removed draft, and I am using IEEEconfran template. Here is the results:[image]

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: `.eps` does not work with `pdf` directly. It seems that you have enabled the `draft` option either of your documentclass or of `\usepackage{graphicx}` or it is some setting with `TeXWorks`

Comment: Even if EPS isn't directly supported by pdflatex, [the graphicx package should convert EPS graphics to PDF automatically](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38528/3345). But a MWE will be helpful here (as Christian indicated, it's almost certainly a draft option somewhere).

Comment: You should convert your .eps file to .pdf format with  Siep Koonenberg's excellent tool: `epspdf`, with option `Compute tight bounding box`.

Comment: it looks to me like you are using `[draft]` option which suppresses the image inclusion and just prints the filename.

Comment: I was wondering, how can I find out that I am using draft, I eliminated the draft name in my .tex file. here is my document class \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran} and I am using the following packages: \usepackage[numbers]{natbib}         % bibliography style
\usepackage[final]{epstopdf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{environ}
%\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\epstopdfsetup{update} 
\usepackage{amssymb}. Please let me know if I have mistake!

Comment: Something other than what you've posted is causing the draft problem. I've built a simple document with an EPS figure with as little as `\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran} \usepackage{graphicx} \begin{document} \begin{figure} \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{somefigure} \caption{Figure} \end{figure} \end{document}`, and also using all your other mentioned packages *except* for epstopdf, since it's not required in modern TeX installs. Start with a blank, minimized IEEEtran document with your figure. See if it builds correctly. If not, post *that* MWE as an edit to your question.

Comment: If it does build correctly (and it should), start adding back packages and setup commands a few at a time until the problem occurs. That will give you a clue to where the real problem lies.

Comment: Thanks Mike for the reply, I just run your code with pdfLaTex and I got the following error: 
Package pdftex.def Error: File `3DPCC-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found.
See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.

Comment: Automatic conversion should have been the default for several years now. What version of TeX Live or MiKTeX do you have?

Comment: I have MiKTeX 2.9

Comment: I suppose it's possible MiKTeX requires the `epstopdf` package as well, but I don't use it myself. If adding `epstopdf` makes my small document compile, then my previous advice still applies (start adding back a few commands at a time to see where the problem starts happening).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding something like this just after `\documentclass`.  This of course assumes you have `xetex` installed.

```
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
    \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
    \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png}
\else
    \usepackage[dvips,xetex]{graphicx}
    \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}
\fi
```

Comment: Thanks, I received the following error: ! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package graphicx.                    
l.283     \DeclareGraphicsExtensions
                                    {.pdf,.jpeg,.png}

Comment: I just compiled the following code with a eps figure showing up with no bug using both latex and xelatex:\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
 \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
   \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png}
\else
 \usepackage[dvips,xetex]{graphicx}
 \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}
\fi
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width = 1\textwidth, clip = true, trim = 0in 0in 0in 0in]{test.eps}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

Comment: Thanks a lot! finally I could. I used both LaTex and XeLaTex and I could able to convert .eps to .pdf format, I do appreciate.